# Create .swf within iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, flash

Can't find anything about this anywhere (maybe there's a good reason...) - does anyone know if there are any libraries for creating simple SWFs in iOS? I'd like to be able to let the user build a simple animation, then email it off as a SWF. If it's not possible, I'll probably go down the animated gif route.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use libsswf which has a c interface.
Check [here](http://sswf.sourceforge.net/libsswf/index.html#c_library).